# object in C#, constructor and overload constructor

Tags: c#

I have and program calculate the square of x-coodinate and y-coodinate.
The code in Main.cs is

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace Classes
{
class Program
{
    static void doWork()
    {
        Point origin = new Point();//default constructor
        Point bottomRight = new Point(1366, 768);//overload constructor
        double distance = origin.DistanceTo(bottomRight);
        Console.WriteLine("Distance is:{0}", distance);
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            doWork();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

and the Point.cs like this

```
namespace Classes
{
class Point
{
    private int x, y;
    public Point()
    {
        //Console.WriteLine("Default constructor called");//default constructor
        this.x = -1;
        this.y = -1;
    }
    public Point(int x, int y)
    {
        //Console.WriteLine("x:{0},y:{1}", x, y);//overload constructor
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
    public double DistanceTo(Point other)
    {
        int xDiff = this.x - other.x;//Point()-Point(int)
        int yDiff = this.y - other.y;
        double distance = Math.Sqrt((xDiff * xDiff) + (yDiff * yDiff));
        return distance;
    }
}
```

}

But I dont understand exactly what is this.x and this.y.

when I debug which one of Point() or Point(int x, int y) using to imulation the DistanceTo??

However I still need more help:

double distance = origin.DistanceTo(bottomRight);
what is this code doing? What is obj.obj??

Why dont it look like "double distance = DistanceTo(bottomRight);"

Comment: You do know that Point struct are already available in C#, and that you would only require an extension method to do this extra calculation?

Comment: Inside the first constructor, `public Point()`, there is nothing else called `x` and `y`, so you _might_ leave out `this.` here, since `x` and `y` will refer to the fields on "this" instance anyway. Similarly inside the method `DistanceTo` you _can_ leave out `this.`. But inside the second constructor overload, `public Point(int x, int y)`, the names `x` and `y` without qualification refer to the parameters to the constructor. These names **hide** the fields on the class level. So here you must use `this.` to bypass this name hiding.

Comment: @Icepickle Good to heard News about Point struct. Im newbie of C# and trying to learn c# in MS_VS_C_Sharp_2012_Step_by_Step ebook of Microsoft. So just relax if I asking question so similarly. Just trying to understands c#.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen thanks Jeppe, thats good answers. Thump up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside of constructor

```
public Point(int x, int y)
{
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}
```

`this.x` and `this.y` refers to class variables (`private int x, y;`) where just `x` and just `y` refer to parameters that are passed to constructor.

In method `DistanceTo()` `this.x` and `this.y` refer to the values of fields `x` and `y` in the same object where `other.x` and `other.y` refer to the values of fields `x` and `y` in the object `other`.